# Jakarta HttpClient issue with size of tag

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons

I have service witch is returning rather simple XML in body, but with very large text in "ns:responses" tag - in IE/Chrome it is approx. 40kB, but in HttpClient I am getting:

```
<ns:InvokeResponse xmlns:ns="...">
<ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns:ServiceResponse">
<ns:responses>TOO MANY CHARACTERS</ns:responses>
<ns:returnCode>0</ns:returnCode>
</ns:return>
</ns:InvokeResponse>
```

I am using code from example of HttpClient:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createMinimal();
try {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(request);
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

    try {
        System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();

        entity1.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));

        EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
    } finally {
        response1.close();
    }
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Any idea what might how can it be improved that the library will correctly read big chunk of characters in one tag so I have correct data instead of 'TOO MANY CHARACTERS'?

Answer (score 0):

The application/library is fine. This was error in URL and the answer was correct answer from server.